# Search and replace a multi-line pattern with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I've seen a lot of examples regarding this problem, but have yet to see the one that is tailored for my use. Although I'm very familiar with sed I'm ashamed to say that I'm a noob when it comes to more advanced features. Here's the problem at hand.

I have a multi-line pattern that I can successfully match with sed like so,

`sed -e '/Favorite Animals/, /!/p`

```
Favorite Animals
Monkey
Penguin
Cat
!
Favorite Things
Shoe
Dog
Wheel
Moth
!
```

and what I personally like about this expression is that I can match a variable number of lines up to the exclamation character. Now let's say I wanted to do a search and replace on that same pattern. Basically I would like to replace that multi-line pattern that was previously demonstrated with any string of my choosing. Any Ideas? I'm hoping for similar syntax to my demonstrated sed command, but beggars can't be choosers.

The idea is so that I can replace one of the groups delimited by the exclamation with a string. I'll call them "entries". I want to be able to update or overwrite these entries. If I had a new updated version of favorite animals I would like to be able to replace the old entry with a new one like this.

```
Favorite Animals
Sloth
Platypus  
Badger
Dog
!
Favorite Things
Shoe
Dog
Wheel
Moth
!
```

As you can see I'm no longer a fan of monkeys now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a variety of options — the `i`, `c`, and `a` commands can all be used.

#### Amended answer

This amended answer deals with the modified data file now in the question.  Here's a mildly augmented version of the modified `data` file:

```
There's material at the start of the file then the key information:
Favourite Animals
Monkey
Penguin
Cat
!
Favourite Things
Shoe
Wheel
Moth
!
and some material at the end of the file too.
```

All three of these `sed` scripts produce the same output:

```sh
sed '/Favourite Animals/,/!/c\
Favourite Animals\
Sloth\
Platypus\
Badger\
!
' data

sed '/Favourite Animals/i\
Favourite Animals\
Sloth\
Platypus\
Badger\
!
/Favourite Animals/,/!/d' data

sed '/Favourite Animals/a\
Favourite Animals\
Sloth\
Platypus\
Badger\
!
/Favourite Animals/,/!/d' data
```

Sample output:

```
There's material at the start of the file then the key information:
Favourite Animals
Sloth
Platypus
Badger
!
Favourite Things
Shoe
Wheel
Moth
!
and some material at the end of the file too.
```

It is crucial that the scripts all use the unique string, `/Favourite Animals/` and do not key off the repeated trailing context `/!/`.  If the `i` or `a` use `/!/` instead of `/Favourite Animals/`, the outputs change — and not for the better.

`/!/i`:

```
There's material at the start of the file then the key information:
Favourite Animals
Sloth
Platypus
Badger
!
Favorite Things
Shoe
Wheel
Moth
Favourite Animals
Sloth
Platypus
Badger
!
!
and some material at the end of the file too.
```

`/!/a`:

```
There's material at the start of the file then the key information:
Favourite Animals
Sloth
Platypus
Badger
!
Favorite Things
Shoe
Wheel
Moth
!
Favourite Animals
Sloth
Platypus
Badger
!
and some material at the end of the file too.
```

#### Extra request

> Would it be possible to select a range within a range using sed? Basically, what if I wanted to change or remove one/many of my favorite animals within the previously specified range. That is `/Favorite Animals/,/!/...` change something within this range.

Yes, of course.  For a single mapping:

```
 sed '/Favourite Animals/,/!/ s/Monkey/Gorilla/'
```

For multiple mappings:

```
 sed '/Favourite Animals/,/!/ {
      s/Monkey/Gorilla/
      s/Penguin/Zebra/
      s/Cat/Dog/
      }'
```

You can also combine those onto a single line if you wish — use semicolons to separate them:

```
 sed '/Favourite Animals/,/!/ { s/Monkey/Gorilla/; s/Penguin/Zebra/; s/Cat/Dog/; }'
```

Be aware that GNU `sed` and BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` have different views on the necessity for the last semicolon — what's shown works with both.

---

The original answer works with a simpler input file.

#### Original answer

Consider the file `data` containing:

```
There's material
at the start of the file
then the key information:
Favourite Animals
Monkey
Penguin
Cat
!
and material at the end of the file too.
```

Using `c`, you might write:

```sh
$ sed '/Favourite Animals/,/!/c\
> Replacement material\
> for the favourite animals
> ' data
There's material
at the start of the file
then the key information:
Replacement material
for the favourite animals
and material at the end of the file too.
$
```

Using `i`, you would use:

```
$ sed '/Favourite Animals/i\
> Replacement material\
> for the favourite animals
> /Favourite Animals/,/!/d' data
There's material
at the start of the file
then the key information:
Replacement material
for the favourite animals
and material at the end of the file too.
$
```

Using `a`, you might write:

```
$ sed '/!/a\
> Replacement material\
> for the favourite animals
> /Favourite Animals/,/!/d' data
There's material
at the start of the file
then the key information:
Replacement material
for the favourite animals
and material at the end of the file too.
$
```

Note that with:

- `c` — you change the whole range
- `i` — you insert before the first pattern in the range before you delete the entire range
- `a` — you append after the last pattern in the range before you delete the entire range

Though, come to think of it, you could insert before the last pattern in the range before deleting the entire range, or append after the first pattern in the range before deleting the entire range.  So, the key with `i` and `a` is to put the 'replacement text' operation before the range-based delete.  But `c` is most succinct.

Comment: Thank you! I like the c command the most because It is most similar to what I was using, but the rest was equally valuable. Seeing as how you answered my first question I have another for you. Would it be possible to select a range within a range using sed? Basically, what if I wanted to change or remove one/many of my favorite animals within the previously specified range. IE `/Favorite Animals/,/!/`... change something within this range. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extra answer to your extra question.  However, be very wary of asking such questions after you've been given answers — they can make your request into a _chameleon question_, and they are not popular.  If you have a new question, you should usually ask a new question.  That could (probably should) refer to the previous question, but should still be a free-standing, self-contained question that is coherent and otherwise worthy in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

The `i` (insert) command has ugly syntax, but it works:

```
sed '/Favorite Animals/i\
some new text\
some more new text\
and a little more
/Favorite Animals/,/!/d'
```

Comment: And there's the similar `a` (append) and `c` (change) commands.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, but the `c` fouls up the deletion, and the `a`... works. That surprises me.